# Automatically import/deploy/distribute private key to users for use with S/MIME

Tags: key-management, key, smime, exchange, outlook

it is an Environment with Microsoft Active Directory, Exchange and Windows/Outlook as Client. Now there are the users which have their own private certificates to send signed mails and encrypt decrypted mails for themself, but all users also access a central mailbox where they should be able to do the same but for this central mailbox.
So there is a private key for this central Mailbox
But how do i distribute the private key to all users, so they can read and sign mails as the central mailbox? Is there a way to install the private key automatically instead of importing the private key manually?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a PGP Key Management Server associated with some sort of desktop app like https://www.gpg4win.org

There are plenty of guides if you google/duckduckgo how to setup a key server

Comment: nope, i am looking for a solution for s/smime, not pgp and Google/duckduckgo doesnt deliver any Solutions. Anyway, i think pgp key Management Servers are mostly for Publishing public certs, not the private keys....

Comment: @Blafasel so, I guess I'm a little confused here. are you trying to have it so emails sent and received to people outside your org. are encrypted? at that point just setup edge rules and encryption at the gateway

Comment: @Matt No, OP is trying to make it so that all emails can be sent signed (requires a private key), and all users have a certificate (and its private key) that can be sent (without private key) to others (internal or external) so that they can encrypt messages back to the user (Outlook automatically includes the cert, with public key, in signed email by default). Given that S/MIME are (Open)PGP are completely different standards (even though they have similar use cases), it's pretty obvious the request was not for how to set up a PGP key server.